# if (!empty($thing)) vs if($thing)

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Are these two statements executed identically, given `$thing` could be of any type?

```
if (!empty($thing)) {
    // do stuff
}

if ($thing) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm aware I could try it, but I'm not sure I'd catch all the edge cases...  I'm afraid in some situations they would execute identically, but not all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$thing` is undefined, then `if ($thing)` would throw a (non-fatal) error while `if (!empty($thing))` would return false.

See [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) in the PHP documentation.

Comment: `if (!empty($thing)` would evaluate as `false`.

Comment: Actually it gives a E_WARNING

Comment: No there is a big difference. An error in PHP is something that breaks the script and stop it. A warning in the most cases is simply ignored.

Comment: @zzzzBov - nope, the E_ prefix stands for Enumeration.  E_NOTICE is not an error, either.

Comment: `E_WARNING` is a non-fatal error http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: It's better to use `!empty` unless it's absolutely necessary to use the variable. But of course, it will throw a warning.

Comment: @TheSmose, I can't disagree with your claim, however I had always assumed that the `E_` in `E_*` constants stood for error, as they represent different error levels. Can you provide any evidence to support your claim? I haven't found any to support mine yet.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Sorry, I actually misspoke there... had crossed wires for a moment.  I know for a fact that in PHP lang constants, T_ stands for "type", so it's likely that E_ stands for "error".

Answer (score 2):

`if (empty($foo))` is the negative of `if ($foo)`, which can easily be seen in the [type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), which means that on the lowest level:

```
if (!empty($foo))
```

is logically the same as

```
if ($foo)
```

*However*, for undefined variables, or array indices, `if ($foo)` and `if ($foo['bar'])` will cause an `E_WARNING` to occur, while `if (!empty($foo))` and `if (!empty($foo['bar']))` will **not**.

To that effect, you should prefer `empty` and `!empty` in cases where the variable or index might not exist, such as with `$_GET` or `$_POST`. In cases where the variable or index *should* exist, you should prefer `$var` and `!$var` specifically so that the warnings thrown are tracked, as they would likely be due to bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant manual pages are [Converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) and, of course, [empty()](http://php.net/empty). For `empty()` we have this:

> A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals `FALSE`

So they're fully equivalent except in the situation where a variable does not exist. And in that case:

```
var_dump( empty($not_exists), (bool)$not_exists );
```

... we get:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

... (among the corresponding `notice`) because:

> the following values are considered `FALSE`: [...]  unset variables

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences according to the manual, for example:

```
$object = new stdclass;
if ($object) {} // false in PHP 4, true in PHP 5+
```

Also, you can only pass variables to `empty`, this will throw an error:

```
if (empty(time()) {}
// Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

if (time()) {} // OK
```

And of course, `if ($var)` on an uninitialized variables will produce a notice.

`if ($var)` is an implicit boolean conversion. See the manual for details.

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php
>
> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

Compare to `empty`

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)
> - $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

So they are basically the same but with a couple very subtle differences. Use both with caution, and do type checking when possible.

Answer (score 0):

empty can blow up horribly in certain cases, the biggest of which is `0` values

```
php > $x = 0;
php > var_dump(empty($x));
bool(true)
php > $x = false;
php > var_dump(empty($x));
bool(true);
```

as long as you're not requiring 0/false values to pass through, then empty() works out great.